Doubt about Polar coordinates
I know that for motion that does not involve rotation relative velocity of a object say $a$ with respect to $b$ can be calculated as $$\mathbb v_{ab}=\mathbb v_{ao}-\mathbb v_{bo}$$where $o$ is some other point.
My question is what happens when we express velocity in polar coordinates, for example, if two bodies say $a$ and $b$ move with velocities $v\hat r$ with respect to some point $o$. (In the general case path of $a$ and $b$ will not be coincident and they will move with father apart)
So if I use the formula I will get that
$$\mathbb v_{ab}=v\hat r -v\hat r=0$$
But this is not true.

In general, each body will have a velocity component in the $\hat{r}$ direction and ALSO in the $\hat{\theta}$ direction.  You have to express $v$ in these coordinates.

I m sorry I should have mentioned , I took the case where component of velocity in tangential direction is zero and it is v in radial direction , so generally the objects would follow two lines that make some angle at the origin. Is this clear?

$\hat r$ depends on θ, and points a and b will in general have different θ, so their respective $\hat r$ are not equal.

I you want a straight line in polar coordinates. Write it in Cartesian:
$$ x(t) = x_0 + v_x t $$
$$ y(t) = y_0 + v_y t $$
so in polar coordinates:
$$ r(t) = \sqrt{x^2(t) + y^2(t)}$$
$$ r(t) = \sqrt{r_0^2 + 2(\vec r_0\cdot
\vec v_0)t + v_0^2t^2}$$
$$ r(t) = |\vec r_0 + \vec v_0 t| $$
$$\theta(t) = \frac{y_0+v_y t}{x_0+v_x t}$$
From there, find $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$ at $\vec r(t)$ and project $\vec v_0$ onto them.

Although there is a difference between expressing a coordinate $(x,y)$ in terms of polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ and expressing a vector in terms of unit vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$. The latter only involves knowing the $\theta$ "coordinate" of wherever the vector in consideration is. e.g. an object with velocity $v_0\hat r$ on the negative x-axis has a velocity of $v_0\hat x$ because $\theta=\pi$.

The unit vectors in polar coordinates $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$ are not uniform across space. We can easily see this by considering the unit vector $\hat x$. This vector would be equal to $-\hat r$ along the positive x-axis, $\hat r$ along the negative x-axis, and even $\hat\theta$ along the positive y-axis.
Therefore, in general you can't take two vectors represented as $\mathbf v_{ao}=v_{ao}\hat r$ and $\mathbf v_{bo}=v_{bo}\hat r$ and just subtract (or add) them as $(v_{ao}-v_{bo})\hat r$. If object a is moving along the negative x-axis and object b is moving along the positive x-axis, then to combine the velocity vectors in this way you need to change to a Cartesian system:
$$\mathbf v_{ab}=\mathbf v_{ao}-\mathbf v_{bo}=v_{ao}\hat x-(-v_{bo}\hat x)=(v_{ao}+v_{bo})\hat x$$
You can generalize this to any type of linear motion that isn't confined to a specific axis.

Like the comment already expressed, you are only taking part of the whole equation. If you were to fully express the velocities of both objects, you would have to look at all components:
$\vec{v} = v_r\hat{r} + v_\theta\hat{\theta}$.
From this point onward, we can start again about looking for relatives of motion. Do you know how $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ looks?
I believe that maybe your mistake comes about from thinking about polar coordinates the same way you would think about Cartesian. But this is not the case. For example, if you have a rotating disc, the outside would spin faster than the inside, and this only happens because the radius outside is larger and travels a further distance. Polar Coordinates are far more intertwined with itself.

I don't have an answer, so I'm piggybacking here: you need a manifold with a position dependent metric an some $\Gamma^i_{jk}$...a real mess...but good practice for GR. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UVJTYL4pQk or http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/29-christoffel-symbol-use-case-calculation-in-polar-coordinates and so on.

I guess, this would be the correct way to handle this. hehe. :)

But wouldn't $v_{\theta}\hat \theta$ make the particle rotate ? it will have an angular velocity equal to $\frac{v_{\theta}}{R}$ I don't want that , rather I want the particles to have straight line trajectories.

This is an interesting remark. You can still get straight lines. Straight lines at least in Cartesian Space or what you consider. Your $v_\theta$ and $v_r$ would not be constant anymore, they would depend on the position.

You can try it yourself. Pick a trajectory, for example (t,t). Derive it, you get (1,1) for the velocity. Now you have to multiply it by both $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$. You will see that those are dependent on the angle $\theta$.
